# score_cbow_pair in word2vec (gensim)

Tags: python, numpy, probability, gensim, word2vec

I wanted to output the log-probability during learning of the word and doc vectors in gensim. I have taken a look at the implementation of the score function in the "slow plain numpy" version.

```py
def score_cbow_pair(model, word, word2_indices, l1):
    l2a = model.syn1[word.point]  # 2d matrix, codelen x layer1_size
    sgn = (-1.0)**word.code  # ch function, 0-> 1, 1 -> -1
    lprob = -log(1.0 + exp(-sgn*dot(l1, l2a.T)))
    return sum(lprob)
```

The score function should make use of the parameters learned during hierarchical softmax training. But in the calculation of the log-probability there is supposed to be a sigmoid function( [word2vec Parameter Learning Explained equation (45)](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf)).
So does gensim really calculate the log-probability in `lprob` or is it just a score for comparison purposes.

I would have calculated the log-probability as follows:
`-log(1.0/(1.0+exp(-sgn*dot(l1, l2a.T))))`

Is this equation not used because it explodes for values close to zero or is it in general wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overlooked that the logarithm of the sigmoid function can be rewritten: `log(1.0/(1.0+exp(-sgn*dot(l1, l2a.T)))) = log(1)-log(1.0+exp(-sgn*dot(l1, l2a.T))) = -log(1.0+exp(-sgn*dot(l1, l2a.T)))`

So the code does compute the log-likelihood.